# sharepoint 2010 Add value in site column using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

hi
my requirement is add value in my site column using javascript
The main thing is that first of all i want to check my site column if it is currently exist then add my value in that but if it is not exist then create new site column using javascript and then add value into that .........
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the javascript code in this blog post. It shows how to use the client object model to retrieve a list item and update the value of a column.

http://blog.dennus.net/2010/07/20/using-the-sp2010-client-object-model-to-update-a-list-item/